# Array List en java

Tags: java, java-8

Tengo en una clase principal los siguientes atributos;

ArrayList(de tipo Libro) libros. en la clase Libro solo tengo las siguientes propiedades:

```
String marca;
int cantidad;
```

Si en la clase principal tengo el método:

void ingresarLibro (String nombre, int cantidad) en la cual creo un libro y lo añado al `ArrayList`.

Mi pregunta es:

Si por ejemplo ingreso `("pepito", 20)` y posteriormente vuelvo a ingresar `("pepito", 30)`, la cantidad del libro ya existente se sume. Es decir ¿cómo puedo hacer que el Libro con la marca de `pepito`, tenga un valor de 50?

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta, tiene muchos errores de ortografía.

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema no necesita un `ArrayList`. Debido a que quieres saber si algo ya existe o no, la mejor solución a tu problema es usar un `HashMap` y no un `ArrayList`, donde la llave sea un String con el nombre del libro, y el valor el libro como tal.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      HashMap<String, Book> nameToBookHashMap = new HashMap<String, Book>();

      addBook("NombreA", 10, nameToBookHashMap);
      addBook("NombreB", 4, nameToBookHashMap);
      addBook("NombreA", 10, nameToBookHashMap);

      for (Book b : nameToBookHashMap.values()) {
          System.out.println(b);
      }
  }

  public static void addBook(String name, int cantidad, HashMap<String, Book> nameToBookHashMap) {
      if (nameToBookHashMap.containsKey(name)) {
          nameToBookHashMap.get(name).addCantidad(cantidad);
          return;
      }

      Book book = new Book(name, cantidad);
      nameToBookHashMap.put(name, book);
  }
}

class Book {
    public int cantidad;
    public String nombre;

    public Book(String nombre, int cantidad) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }

    public void addCantidad(int cantidad) {
        this.cantidad += cantidad;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.nombre + " : " + this.cantidad;
    }
}
```

Te dejo el siguiente ejemplo de como podría hacerse utilizando un HashMap. Puedes probar el código en este enlace: https://replit.com/@JacoboTapia/BooksCount#Main.java

Sin embargo si necesitas utilizar un `ArrayList`, lo que debes hacer es sobreescribir el método equals en tu clase `Libro`, para poder utilizar los métodos `indexOf` del `ArrayList` y verificar si un objeto ya existe o no en tu arreglo.Y de existir, actualizar dicho índice.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

      addBook("NombreA", 10, books);
      addBook("NombreB", 4, books);
      addBook("NombreA", 10, books);

      for (Book b : books) {
          System.out.println(b);
      }
  }

  public static void addBook(String name, int cantidad, ArrayList<Book> books) {
      Book b = new Book(name, 0);

      int index = books.indexOf(b);
      if (index != -1) {
          books.get(index).addCantidad(cantidad);
          return;
      }

      b.addCantidad(cantidad);
      books.add(b);
  }
}

class Book {
    public int cantidad;
    public String nombre;

    public Book(String nombre, int cantidad) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }

    public void addCantidad(int cantidad) {
        this.cantidad += cantidad;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return this.nombre.equals(((Book)other).nombre);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.nombre + " : " + this.cantidad;
    }
}
```

El código anterior hace uso de `ArrayList` y puedes probar su funcionamiento aquí https://replit.com/@JacoboTapia/BooksArrayListCount#Main.java

Comment: Se q es mejor un hashMap  pero me lo piden con ArrayList

Comment: Entonces en tu clase Libro has un `override` de la clase equals para que compare el String de nombre. Posteriormente crea un libro dummy para que puedas utilizar el método `indexOf` del ArrayList. Si el índice es -1 significa que el libro no existe. Si el indice es mayor o igual a 0, sus ese indice en el método `get` del ArrayList para actualizar el libro en dicho índice.

Comment: Actualice la respuesta con ArrayList.

Comment: nose como funciona mucho esta pagina pero creo q me respondi el mensaje arriba donde te muestro el codigo que va, osea las clases y sus cosas

Comment: Edita tu pregunta, no puedes poner tu problema como una respuesta.Como sea tu acercamiento está mal. Como quieres relacionar la cantidad con pepito, si pepito no tiene una variable directa que lo relacione con una cantidad. esa cantidad esta flotando, ningún libro es su dueño y no existe una relación con la puedas decir que Pepito tiene una cantidad de x. Por eso la cantidad debe estar dentro de libro yno volando por si sola y sin relación en el main.

Answer (score -1):

esta bien pero no es a lo que me referia inicialmente, es decir, lo que tengo es

```
class Libro{
    String nombre;
}

class main{
    ArrayList(Libro) libros;
    int cantidad;

    void ingresarLibro( String nombre, int cantidad){}

}
```

Comment: Esto se añade a tu pregunta, no a tu respuesta. Y es lo mismo, solo cambias el método ingresar libro para pasar el array list al que se van a añadir los libros y así tener referencia de los objetos que ya añadiste.

Comment: Segundo, no entiendo porque la cantidad esta fuera del ArrayList. Si la cantidad de libros esta relacionada con el nombre del libro, no hay razón para que haya una cantidad global de libros que no está relacionada a ningún libro en específico.